# Why won't my iPad mini’s gyroscope work?

Tags: ipad

Ever since I updated my iPad mini to iOS 7.0.6 when I twist it around from vertical to horizontal, the picture won't turn with it. Is this a bug or is my iPad mini broken?

Answer (score 1):

try switching the button above the volume rocker, if it shows a rotation lock/unlock icon that should fix it.
If it shows an mute unmute icon swipe up from the bottom to reveal the quick-acces menu, in there there should be an icon for locking and unlocking the rotation of your iPad.
Let me know if this fixed it.